# Needing Specific Kinetic.Transform Example using KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am wondering how to transform text using KineticJS in order to mirror or reflect Simple Text. I see that the class is documented at this location:

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Transform.html

There is no sample code, or tutorial, on how to actually perform this demonstration. I know that HTML5 Canvas has a tutorial that simply applies a negative scale in the x direction to flip the context horizontally.

I would like to apply "scale(sx, sy)" or scale(-1, 1) here, but using KineticJS-specific code:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/

Any code example on how to mirror "Simple Text" to read "txeT elpmiS" would be greatly appreciated. My question, on Stackoverflow, is not the only question being asked about KineticJS's undocumented functionality, so I am hoping that being more specific in purpose would generate a more helpful response for overall guidance on using the Transform Class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Transform` class. It is "private".

You can apply negative scale at text as well:

```
simpleText.scale({
  x : -1
});
```

http://jsbin.com/sevoko/1/edit